# Does 51% of CNBC climate coverage deny that climate change is caused by man-made pollution?

Tags: climate-change, media, al-gore

Here is the source of the claim:

- [Mediamatter for America climate statistics graph](http://ow.ly/i/2oset)
- [Tweeted, and re-tweeted by Al Gore](https://twitter.com/ClimateReality/status/347116690229825536)
- The source that the image refers to: [REPORT: CNBC's Climate Denial Is Bad For Business](http://mediamatters.org/research/2013/06/18/report-cnbcs-climate-denial-is-bad-for-business/194483)

The text in the [image](http://mediamatters.org/research/2013/06/18/report-cnbcs-climate-denial-is-bad-for-business/194483) says:

> 51% of CNBC climate coverage denies that climate change is caused by man-made pollution

Is this true?

The [text](http://ow.ly/i/2oset) from Media Matters for America says:

> Twenty-four out of the 47 substantial mentions or segments on climate change on CNBC, or just over 51 percent of coverage, cast doubt on whether manmade climate change existed.

Is this true?

Comment: Is this notable? News stations cover the news.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be tested, or why you're skeptical of it. They document their method. The only test of it would be to replicate the study

Comment: I would be quite surprised that 51% of mentions of climate change explicitly state a position on whether it's manmade, let alone deny it. I mean, what, are anchors saying "Now let's go to Bob, who is on location reporting on this hurricane, which definitely was not caused by man-made pollution"? "And now an interview with Jane Smith, whose house was destroyed by a flood that definitely was not caused by man-made pollution"? The phrase "cast doubt" sounds like weasel words to me.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers What "documentation" is there? Where do they say what counts as "casting doubt"? How do you go from "cast doubt" to "deny"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too old to be useful.

Comment: What news organizations do very frequently is interview someone who believes climate change is man-made and then interview someone who does not. They do this because of balance, and it's standard practice. If that counts as "casting doubt on whether manmade climate change existed" then it's absolutely expected.